# How to access localhost on rootless docker

Tags: linux, docker, rootless

I tried:

```
services:
  susebox:
    build: .
    entrypoint: 
      - python3 
      - -m 
      - http.server
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

but I can't do curl to `host.docker.internal.` ping is working on `host.docker.internal` but I still can't access the service running on localhost:

```
#inside of the container 

curl http://host.docker.internal:8080/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

Also tried

```
network_mode: "host"

curl http://localhost:8080/ #this runs ok outside of container
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

but I still can't reach localhost from inside of docker container. I'm using [rootless docker containers](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/docker-rootless-extras)

Comment: You have exposed port 8000 to your local machine, not port 8080 which is what your curl is doing.

Comment: @alex067 that curl cmd if from inside of container. there is http server running on 8080 on my localhost which I want to access from inside of container

Comment: Then from inside the container you should connect to `host.docker.internal:8080` which is how your docker host (i.e. your development machine) is known. From inside the container, `localhost` is the container itself.

Comment: @Zeitounator it does not work. see edit

Comment: Are you running on linux, windows, or mac? Windows and mac run docker in a lightweight VM which effects how this can be done. `host.docker.internal` for instance, is only available on windows and mac docker.

Comment: @NikNye I'm on Linux (Arch btw)

Comment: I would suggest you edit the question and provide a lot more detail

Comment: `Connection refused` <= I suspect your service on your machine only accepts connections from localhost (i.e. the same machine where it runs).

Comment: @alex067 what more details do I need to add ? most people commenting/answing here dont even seem to know what rootless containers are or what OS i'm using even if linux is clearly tagged.

Comment: @Zeitounator its darkhttpd server and I can even access it from my android phone

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're using the `slirp4netns` network driver, since that's what the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) implicitly suggests.

Docker rootless runs `slirp4netns` with the `--disable-host-loopback` option, which prohibits connecting to `127.0.0.1:*` on the host namespace, presumably for security reasons.

If the host service is listening on `0.0.0.0` you can try connecting to the local network IP of the host, for instance `192.168.1.100`.

If you have to access a service listening on the host's `127.0.0.1` or don't want to change your configuration (e.g. because it's shared with others that don't use docker rootless), you could use [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to forward traffic between namespaces using a socket.

Suppose you want to access `127.0.0.1:8080` running on the host from inside a container. You would need 2 `socat` instances for that:

1. An instance listening on a unix socket that forwards traffic to `127.0.0.1:8080`:

   ```
   socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/forward-docker.socket,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:8080
   ```
2. An instance running on the docker namespace that forwards traffic to the socket created by the previous command:

   ```
   nsenter -U --preserve-credentials -n -t $(cat "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.pid") -- socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr,fork /tmp/forward-docker.socket
   ```

The trick here is that the networks are isolated between namespaces, but the filesystem is shared, so we use an unix socket to bridge the gap. Note that these commands run on the host. After that you can access that host port from inside any container.

If the service you're trying to access is running in another container and forwarding a port on the host, you can skip the first instance and only run the one in the namespace, but you would need to change the port, as it would have already been used by docker in the namespace, and forward to `127.0.0.1`. For instance, let's say you are running a service like this:

```
docker network create another-net
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 --net another-net python python -m http.server 8080
```

You only need command #2 but with a different port, for example `8081`:

```
nsenter -U --preserve-credentials -n -t $(cat "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.pid") -- socat TCP4-LISTEN:8081,reuseaddr,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:8080
```

And then from any other container you would access the new port.

An example bash script to do all that in a single easy command, with the option of binding different ports:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

PORTS=($(echo "$1" | grep -oP '^\d+(:\d+)?$' | sed -e 's/:/ /g'))
if [ -z $PORTS ]; then
    cat <<EOF
Usage:
$(basename "$0") SRC[:DEST]
    SRC: will be the port accessible inside the container
    DEST:
        the connection will be redirected to this port on the host.
        if not specified, the same port as SRC will be used
EOF
    exit 1
fi

SOURCE=${PORTS[0]}
DEST=${PORTS[1]-${PORTS[0]}}

SOCKFILE="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/forward-docker2host-${SOURCE}_$DEST.sock"
socat UNIX-LISTEN:"$SOCKFILE",fork TCP:127.0.0.1:$DEST &
nsenter -U --preserve-credentials -n -t $(cat "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.pid") -- socat TCP4-LISTEN:$SOURCE,reuseaddr,fork "$SOCKFILE" &
echo forwarding $SOURCE:$DEST... use ctrl+c to quit
sleep 365d
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a Virtual Ethernet pair for this. The idea is to have one end of the pair in the host's network namespace, the other end in the container's network namespace. With the script below, you can access any port of the host from the container by referring to the IP `192.168.100.1`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# This script creates a bridge between a ROOTLESS Docker container's and the host's network namespace.
# This should allow a rootless Caddy container to (reverse) proxy requests to apps running in the host's network namespace.

# Specify the user running the rootless Docker daemon
DOCKER_USER="<YOUR USER HERE THAT IS RUNNING THE DOCKER DAEMON>"

# Create the VETH pair
ip link add caddyhost type veth peer name caddycontainer

# Assign IP addresses to each end of the VETH pair
ip addr add 192.168.100.1/24 dev caddyhost
ip link set caddyhost up

# Use 'sudo -u' to run 'docker inspect' as the Docker user
pid=$(sudo -u $DOCKER_USER docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' caddy)

ip link set caddycontainer netns $pid
nsenter -t $pid -n ip addr add 192.168.100.2/24 dev caddycontainer
nsenter -t $pid -n ip link set caddycontainer up
```

This script needs to be run as root on the host. If the Docker container is recreated, it needs to be run again as that operation breaks the VETH pair.